# Pytest can't generate XML output when in unicode

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, pep8, pytest

1. Go to project src
2. run `py.test --pep8 --junitxml=pep8.log`

First console shows .py files pytest already tested, than it brakes with a message:

```
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_pytest\junitxml.py", line 134, in append_failure
INTERNALERROR>     fail.append(str(report.longrepr))
INTERNALERROR> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1430-1434: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to fix this by transforming `fail.append(str(report.longrepr))` to  `fail.append(str(report.longrepr.encode("utf-8")))` but pytest continues failing on the other lines of this file and _xmlgen.py file.

I think there is a better way to fix this globally then editing every line of code it fails on.

Comment: Found fix for this: https://bitbucket.org/apkawa/pytest/commits/1a284b99104e2d525b46a13a0fffff081158377a but now it fails in py package: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py\_xmlgen.py", line 133, in __object
    self.write(escape(unicode(obj)))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 1305: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I filed an issue for oytest developer and it was fixed: https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/368/unicode-error-when-launching-pytest

Comment: If you have answered your own question, perhaps you can write an answer and accept it? This will allow the question to show up as "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed an issue for pytest developer and it was fixed https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/368/unicode-error-when-launching-pytest